# Swift AutoLayout: UITextViews inside UIScrollView headache

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitextview

I'm trying to wrap my head around how `UIScrollViews` work and while there are already some pretty good answers, they don't seem to cover `UITextViews`, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me more about what UITextViews require to work in a UIScrollView. My setup looks like the image below and I'm getting errors that the ScrollView has no height or width constraints.

If you could, I'd appreciate it if you could elaborate a little on why this doesn't work and what requirements TextViews have when placed inside ScrollViews.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi can you share this storyboard with us, it would be easier to detect what actually is wrong, but for a start try to remove `"Scrolling Enabled"` checkmark from UITextView in Attributes Inspector

Comment: Hey @Andrew isScrollable is disabled on the textviews. You can see the full storyboard here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7q1lbj0pxx14jh/Main.storyboard?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So https://www.dropbox.com/s/gujry7ngziaipm7/Main.storyboard?dl=0 here is the fixed variant.
I found a few errors:

1. Top constraint from `Title Input` was to view from another hierarchy
2. `Content View` - your root view in UIScrollView was without x, y constraints, so I added trailing, bottom, top and leading constraint.

And maybe some tips:

- Your constraint should be relative to each other, so you have no need to offset all views from `Safe Layout`.
- Try to separate your `viewControllers` to different Storyboard files, otherwise if you would work in team, it would be a real headache to fix merge problems in git)

Hope it will helps you in your project)

Comment: Aside from what you suggested, I managed to solve it by fixing another issue: the priority of the equal widths between the container view and scroll view was set to 250 and it should have been 1000. Only the equal heights need to be 250. Thanks again.